# Triple Screen working on GNOME Shell but not on Unity

Tags: unity, nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, intel

I'm trying to use my triple-screen setup on Unity, and after a lot of failures, I have still not been able to make it work. Today, as a last resort, I tried on GNOME Shell and ... it worked ! The problem is that, in fact, I don't really like GNOME Shell, and I would like to use Unity.

As it works on GNOME Shell, shouldn't it work on Unity ? On Unity, my third screen is black (no background, no menu), I can put my mouse on it but I am not able to drag any window on it. (I tried Xinerama, but it only make my first two screens work as if they were one)

*I've seen in an old post that Compiz does not support two separate graphics cards in one machine. So since Unity depends on Compiz, it will simply not work. Is it still true ?*

I am using

- 3 1920x1200 screens
- 1 NVIDIA NVS 4200M (346.96 driver)
- 1 Intel Integrated Graphics Controller

**EDIT - I forgot : Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, GNOME Shell 3.10.4, Unity 7.2.5**

Do you any ideas on how to make it work on Unity ?

Regards,
Adrien T.